# How can I read data from one table then translate it into name from another table

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, odbc

Here is the scenario, I have two tables into my database. One named projects and the other named assigns. In the projects table, I have 2 columns one that has the project ID and the project name. In the assigns table, I have two columns, one employee ID and the other project ID. What I'm trying to do is, when someone search for the projects that an employee is assigned to, I want to show names rather than codes. So, I want to retrieve the project name from projects table in the gridview where this id matches the ids into assigns table.

Here is my trial code:

```
        OdbcCommand assignslist = new OdbcCommand("SELECT projName FROM projects WHERE projID=(SELECT projname FROM assigns where employeeID='" + empid + "')", _connection);
        OdbcDataReader readassigns = assignslist.ExecuteReader();
        GridView1.DataSource = readassigns;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

I receive an error when I try this code. I want to retrieve all of the projects assigned to this employee into a gridview Can someone help please?!

---

### table assigns

employeeID  projname

### EJ201           MD101

### table projects

projID  projName    startDate   endDate
MD101   testa
MD301   testb
MD930   testc

---

### table empos

ID  fName   midName lName
EJ201   jack    joe     joey
EMP201  a       b       c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a [JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) query. But your design (or at least your description) lacks of a fundamental piece of information, the EmployeeName. In your scenario is common to have a third table that containt the information about an Employee with its name and other anagraphic information.

So suppose you have a third table named Employee with

```
 EmployeeID  INT
 Name NVARCHAR(50)
 .....
```

Now you could retrieve all the info about a project with a query like this

```
SELECT p.projID, p.projName , e.ID, e.fName, .........
FROM projects p INNER JOIN assigns a ON p.projID= a.projID
                INNER JOIN empos e ON a.employeeID= e.ID
WHERE a.employeeID = @empID
```

The exact syntax for the JOIN query could be a bit different but the concept is the same. JOIN is used to represent the relationship between two or more tables.

```
string cmdText = "SELECT p.projID, p.projName, e.ID, e.fName, e.midName, e.lName " +
                 "FROM ((projects p INNER JOIN assigns a ON p.projName = a.projname) " +
                 "INNER JOIN empos e ON a.employeeID= e.ID) " +
                 "WHERE a.employeeID = ?";
OdbcCommand assignslist = new OdbcCommand(cmdText, _connection);
assignslist.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empID", empID);
OdbcDataReader readassigns = assignslist.ExecuteReader();
GridView1.DataSource = readassigns;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

I have also changed the way in which you build the query from a string concatenation exposed to Sql Injections and parsing problems to a more secure parameterized query. Here the value for the empID is represented by a placeholder (the question mark) and then the empID value is added to the parameter collection where the Framework code will handle the passing value to the underlying database

**A side note:** from your code is not evident if you close the datareader and the connection. Remember to do that (possibily using the [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx))

**EDIT** With your edit it is now clear that the relationship has been made using the projName, not the projectID, so I update the query above

Comment: Thank you so much. Indeed I have another table called empos that holds all of the employee's data. I tried your code but i'm receiving the following error. ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'p.projID= a.projID INNER JOIN Employee e ON a.employeeID= e.EmployeeID'.

Comment: Added a couple of parenthesys, but it is difficult for me to say where this error is. I suggest to try the query directly in MS Access using a fixed EmployeeID as test. Also check if the names used are exactly the one present in your tables

Comment: I modified my post with more details an all of the tables included into the project.

Comment: I'm still getting an error: ERROR [07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1.

Comment: the field in the projects table is called projid. Fixed